# Understanding Differential Operator?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

$\frac{d}{dx}$ is an operator used often in calculus, but I don't understand this use of notation, for example I saw recently in a problem an expression's derivative given as $\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)$, I'm confused about this, as $f(x)$ refers to a number, and represented as an expression, we cannot have $\frac{d}{dx}$ for example is $\frac{d}{dx}$ acting on the number, or the expression, I understand it mapping between a function $f$ and a function $f'$ but $f(x)$ is not a function but a value. We even see something where we use $\frac{d}{dx}$ without even specifying the function, just as $\frac{d}{dx}(e^x)$.

Do we see it as 'the operator on the function defined by the expression'?

If we cannot substitute into $x$ when an expression is enclosed by the differential operator, we get $\frac{d}{dx}$ (a) which makes no sense, so is $x$ bound in this expression and how does this work considering the expression $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$ depends on the value $x$ which is not how bound variables work.

Comment: People learn to live with the notation, despite its flaws. It just refers to the mapping $f\mapsto f'$ (defined on appropriate spaces, say once-differentiable functions into the space of all real functions). This is purely symbolic; it's quick and easy to write down and gets the point across quickly; it's a notation of practicality, not 'formal correctness'.

Comment: $f(x)$ could refer to a number, but there is long tradition that in calculus we write $f(x)$ rather than $f$. But either way it is a label for a function under discussion.  You may also write $\frac{d}{dx}(f)$ or $f'(x)$.

Comment: If you wish to fix an input in your discussion, it is more common to choose notation $a,b,c$ or $\xi$. So "$f(a)$ refers to a number"

Comment: $f(x)$ is also the value of $f$ at $x$ in it's most simple form, a variable value given by determine the output of $f$ for different $x$, using $a$ might be confusing either way its referring to a variable value.

Comment: You're right, but historically the term "function" and the symbol $f(x)$ referred to symbolic expressions of $x$ (i.e essentially (formal) power series), While we may have now broadened and made precise our definition of "function", it is still (mainly convenience in language and inertia) standard to slip back into the older usage. Now, I'm not advocating such usage, but just pointing out the fact that when people know what they're talking about, they won't always be precise (though students should definitely be made aware of the difference).

Comment: It's kind of like how in grammar classes we learn all these rules, but in everyday conversations (or texting), we don't follow them, and yet people (who are familiar with the language) know what they're talking about and people understand them. Back to math: yes it can be confusing when first seeing this, but that's just the way things are written succinctly, and we have to learn to understand it (and ignore the blatant flaws).

Answer (score 1):

As a comment said: it is just a notation, however I usually see also the notations $\frac{d}{d x}f$, $\frac{d}{d x}\big|_a f$ (the latter to specify the derivative at $a$) or just $\partial f(a)$ (or the more common $f'(a)$).

In your case you can understand the notation $\frac{d}{d x}f(x)$ as the evaluation of the function $\frac{d}{d x}f$ at $x$, that is

$$
\frac{d}{d x}f(x):=\left(\frac{d}{d x}f\right)(x)
$$

Comment: If given $\frac{d}{dx}(f(x) = g(x)$ how come on one side we have a value (the expression that gives the derivative) and on the other we have something that can't be substituted into as subbing in for $x$ in $\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)$ would give $\frac{d}{dx}(f(4)$ which makes no sense.

Comment: @user37577 have you read my answer? Please, read it carefully

Comment: In essence it's a sort of shorthand notation that we don't expect to substitute in for? So really its like saying, $f$ is the function defined by the expression which we are using the differential operator on?

Comment: @user37577 exactly, that is. The notation $\frac{d}{d x}f(x)$ just represent the function $x\mapsto f'(x)$. It is just a costume, as every notation in mathematics. I agree that its unfortunate, and you dont see it in modern mathematical books